# Raspberry Pi:How do I install xtable(s)

Tags: r, raspberry-pi, raspbian

When I run "install.packages("xtable" I get this error: "package ‘xtables’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)"

I downloaded the source but there wasn't a "config" or "setup" file not even a "readme"?

Comment: You write `install.packages("xtable")`, then say that `package ‘xtables’ is not available`. Which is correct? `xtable` or `xtables`? Because package `xtable` exists. Not package `xtables`. I guess you misspelled `xtable` in `install.package`.

Comment: @Pascal,  I tried both "xtable" and "xtables" and got the same error message.....

Comment: Please edit your question to **clearly** show this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`install.packages("xtable", type = "source")`